# rdma unexpected CM event 3 - RDMA_CM_EVENT_ROUTE_ERROR

Tags: network-programming, infiniband, rdma

I am hosting an Infiniband server in a linux machine and also I have created a client and connected to that service in the same machine.This works fine most of the time.
But in one instance when I was trying to connect to that server from the same client (there is no prior connectivity with that server), It is throwing `RDMA_CM_EVENT_ROUTE_ERROR` and the connection couldn't be established.

I don't know the root cause of this error and it is not 100% recreatable.
This made my application unreliable. I want to know the root cause of it..

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your code? Or at least provide a list of the RDMA API calls you have made? In particular, did you try to connect using the same cm_id that used to work before? or is it a brand new instance?

Comment: Actually there is no issue with the RDMA API calls and I couldnt post the code since it is organization confidential. I was able to connect to the sever with no issue and it is working fine now as well..On that random instance I got this RDMA_CM_EVENT_ROUTE_ERROR. I am very much ethusiastic to know what happened on that instance.

Comment: for the same cm_id it was trying to connect for about 4seconds and it failed..For a new instance it was able to obtain the connection with the server